# Mvc cant direct unauthrozied access to login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I simple run application and expect to see login.. but here is the page I see instead:
[image]
I already defined route and form authentication element in web.config file 
here they are:
route:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

homecontroller:

```
[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
```

webconfig:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Auth/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
```

what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the following link it may help you 
http://dotnetdevdude.com/Blog/2011/11/21/ASPNETMVCRedirectToCustomPageWhenUserIsNotAuthorized.aspx

Comment: Yeah I used it and gives me what I want but I wonder why default Authorize attribute not direct to url that defined in web config file..

Comment: [Link-only answers are frowned upon.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/274942) Please include the information in the link; otherwise, link rot can make the answer useless. Thanks!